# WinRT too many errors in base.h

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime

I am using Visual Studio and trying to compile simple WinRT example:
pch.h:

```
// pch.h
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Web.Syndication.h>
#include <iostream>
```

ConsoleApplication2.h:

```
#include "pch.h"
 
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Web::Syndication;
 
int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
 
    Uri rssFeedUri{ L"https://blogs.windows.com/feed" };
    SyndicationClient syndicationClient;
    SyndicationFeed syndicationFeed = syndicationClient.RetrieveFeedAsync(rssFeedUri).get();
    for (const SyndicationItem syndicationItem : syndicationFeed.Items())
    {
        winrt::hstring titleAsHstring = syndicationItem.Title().Text();
        std::wcout << titleAsHstring.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get "too many errors" in winrt\base.h library file.

What I do wrong and how to compile this simple example?

Comment: put all "system" headers in pch.h, Windows.h first, and then pch.h should the first include in this file and remove all others https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=msvc-160

Comment: thank you, but that does not helped me. Project still broken.

Comment: Exact same code works for me (same as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started). Make sure you're running the latest C++/WinRT. Mine is 2.0.210505.3. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264

Comment: Thanks for reply. I change C++ standard to C++17 in project property and that helps a bit. Now I have only 4 errors:
"wait_for" is not a member of "winrt::impl" in Windows.Foundation.0.h. Can you help me with this? I dont know how to check WinRT version, but I checked for updates Visual Studio and there was no any updates.

Comment: Thanks, Simon Mourier,  I think its solved.

Answer (score 2):

I guess i found solution.

Visual Studio Menu -> Project -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Browse

install Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT

Rebuild.